# Retrieving SAS macro from a catalog

Tags: sas, catalog, sas-macro

Can anyone provide the syntax for *retrieving* a SAS Macro from a permanent catalog?  (ie copy it into my work.sasmacr location)

I don't need this as part of my autocall as I won't always be connecting to this library...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it!!

didn't realise it was so simple - pretty much same syntax as creating it in the first place.

```
options mstored sasmstore=MYLIBRARY;

%MYMACRO
```